# Python - Tuple generation from list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have 2 lists `a = [2, 6, 12, 13, 1, 4, 5]` and `b = [12, 1]`. Elements in list `b` are a subset of list `a`.

From the above pair of lists, I need to create a list of tuples as following :

```
[(12,6),(12,2),(1,13),(1,12),(1,6),(1,2)]
```

Basically, at the point of intersection of list `b` and list `a`, so from above e.g `a` and `b` first intersection point is at index `2`, the value `12`. So create a tuple with the first element from list `b` and the second element from list `a`. I am trying this in python, any suggestion for efficiently doing creating this tuple ? Please note, each list can have 100 elements, in it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understans what you need... what is the _point of intersection_ of two lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
a = [2, 6, 12, 13, 1, 4, 5]
b = [12, 1]

sum([ [ (bb,aa) for aa in a[0:a.index(bb)]] for bb in b], [])
```

The result is:

```
[(12, 2), (12, 6), (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 12), (1, 13)]
```

It returns the lists in the original order, while your example returns the list reversed. If that is a problem you can reverse them easily.

Comment: Can you tell me how different is list comprehension from a nested for loop ? And what is efficiency of this algorithm in time ?

Comment: List comprehension is actually _syntactic sugar_ for a loop. Maybe there is some additional optimization opportunities, but I wouldn't count on it. You can save memory using list generators (the comprehension with `()` instead of `[]`, and that may make a difference with very long lists (but not with just 100 elements). About the difference in time, you'll have to profile.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
In [11]: a=[2,6,12,13,1,4,5]

In [12]: b=[12,1]

In [13]: ans=[]

In [14]: for x in b:
    ind=a.index(x)     #find the index of element in a
    for y in a[:ind]:  #iterate up to that index and append the tuple to a new list 
        ans.append((x,y))
   ....:         

In [15]: ans
Out[15]: [(12, 2), (12, 6), (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 12), (1, 13)]
```

using `list comprehension`:

```
In [16]: [(x,y) for x in b for y in a[:a.index(x)]]
Out[16]: [(12, 2), (12, 6), (1, 2), (1, 6), (1, 12), (1, 13)]
```

Comment: The expected output is correct, but looking at more efficient way - without nested for loops ?

Comment: @Swati I've added a list comprehension based solution as well.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, one question since my list b will either contain all or subset of element from list a. Any solution to generate the output from list a itself.?

Comment: I am asking same question to you too, as I asked rodrigo above, since you have also provided the same list comprehension based approached : how different is list comprehension from nested for loop, I am sure it is more than a compressed syntax ?

Comment: @Swati It's `O(N^2)` , but LCs run slightly faster than the simple `for` loops. Read more about list comprehension [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).